.htaccess to access WebSocket server via wss://
I'm using Yjs for a collaborative editor. It involves running a small, fairly straightforward WebSockets signaling server with Node.js. The source code for the server is here.
I start the signaling server with PORT=12201, and I'm trying to connect to the signaling server from my app via wss://<my-server-name>:12201.
On both Chrome and Firefox I get an error: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://<my-server-name>:12201/' failed".
However, if I change it to ws:// and run my app from localhost, it connects just fine. The problem, of course, is that an HTTPS webpage cannot make an insecure (ws://) connection, it must make a secure one (wss://).
You can see in the source code for the server that the connection is started as a plain, insecure WebSocket. Now, I could potentially add the certificate information to the server and start the connection securely, but (a) I don't have the certificate, since I'm currently using Lets Encrypt on DreamHost and I don't have access to it; and (b) I've been advised that it's better practice to let the server or proxy handle encryption rather than adding the certificate info to the server itself.
So after a bunch of Googling, there seem to be similar questions about using a wss:// connection with a ws:// server via .htaccess. So assuming I can get this to work, I've played around with a number of combinations, mostly variations on:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:12201/$1 [P,L]

But that's still not working.
Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, i.e., somehow letting Apache handle SSL for the ws:// connection (i.e., making it wss://), or am I barking up the wrong tree?
